# Tkinter binding: loop repeating itself (Python)

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, event-binding

I'm trying to write a game in which a box moves on the screen according to the arrow keys, and when I press the 'space' button it will pause.

For some reason, when I press the space button it returns to the 'NewGame()' loop as if nothing happened. Why is this happening?

```
from Tkinter import *

HEIGHT = 400
WIDTH = 300
cHEIGHT=HEIGHT-100
cWIDTH=WIDTH
TOPLEFT=3
BUTTOMRIGHT=13
RECTANGLE_SIDE=BUTTOMRIGHT-TOPLEFT

def NewGame():

    def Key(event):
        while True:
            (x1,y1,x2,y2)=canvas.coords(head)
            if event.keysym =='Right':
                canvas.move(head,1,0)
                root.update()
                if x1>=cWIDTH:
                    canvas.move(head, -cWIDTH,0)
            elif event.keysym=='Left':
                canvas.move(head,-1,0)
                root.update()
                if x2<=0:
                    canvas.move(head, cWIDTH,0)
            elif event.keysym=='Up':
                canvas.move(head,0,-1)
                root.update()
                if y2<=0:
                    canvas.move(head, 0,cHEIGHT)
            elif event.keysym=='Down':
                canvas.move(head,0,1)
                root.update()
                if y1>=cHEIGHT:
                    canvas.move(head, 0,-cHEIGHT)
            elif event.keysym=='space':
                break

    canvas.delete("all")
    head=canvas.create_rectangle(TOPLEFT,TOPLEFT,BUTTOMRIGHT,BUTTOMRIGHT)
    root.bind('<Key>', Key)

root = Tk()
root.geometry(('%dx%d')%(HEIGHT,WIDTH))

b1 = Button(root, text = 'New Game', command=NewGame)
b1.pack()

canvas=Canvas(root, height = cHEIGHT, width = cWIDTH)
canvas.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `while` loop.

You set the while loop to run on `True`, which of course means it will run indefinitely unless you break from the loop. The only instance in which you break from the loop is when `event.keysym=='space'`.

Because of this, the while loop will loop infinitely if `event.keysym` equals anything other than `space`.

```
    def Key(event):
        (x1,y1,x2,y2)=canvas.coords(head)
        if event.keysym =='Right':
            canvas.move(head,1,0)
            root.update()
            if x1>=cWIDTH:
                canvas.move(head, -cWIDTH,0)
        elif event.keysym=='Left':
            canvas.move(head,-1,0)
            root.update()
            if x2<=0:
                canvas.move(head, cWIDTH,0)
        elif event.keysym=='Up':
            canvas.move(head,0,-1)
            root.update()
            if y2<=0:
                canvas.move(head, 0,cHEIGHT)
        elif event.keysym=='Down':
            canvas.move(head,0,1)
            root.update()
            if y1>=cHEIGHT:
                canvas.move(head, 0,-cHEIGHT)
        elif event.keysym=='space':
            pass
```

Comment: this does not help, because I want one press on the arrow key, to make it move until a different key was pressed. This is why I used the `while True:` loop. When I run my program, it does not exit the while loop when 'space' is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have that loop running until you encounter the `event.keysym=='space'` condition.

Instead of running the loop on `True` and waiting for the `space` to be pressed to break it, you can try using that condition for the `while` loop, and let it run as long as the `space` has not yet been pressed.

As follows:

```py
    def Key(event):
        while event.keysym!='space':
            (x1,y1,x2,y2)=canvas.coords(head)
            if event.keysym =='Right':
                canvas.move(head,1,0)
                root.update()
                if x1>=cWIDTH:
                    canvas.move(head, -cWIDTH,0)
            elif event.keysym=='Left':
                canvas.move(head,-1,0)
                root.update()
                if x2<=0:
                    canvas.move(head, cWIDTH,0)
            elif event.keysym=='Up':
                canvas.move(head,0,-1)
                root.update()
                if y2<=0:
                    canvas.move(head, 0,cHEIGHT)
            elif event.keysym=='Down':
                canvas.move(head,0,1)
                root.update()
                if y1>=cHEIGHT:
                    canvas.move(head, 0,-cHEIGHT)
```